# HTTP digest authentication using wp_remote_get

Tags: http-api, wp-remote-get

I am able to implement http basic auth in `wp_remote_get` using the following code

```
$args = array(
    'headers' => array(
        'Authorization' => 'Basic ' . base64_encode( $username . ':' . $password )
    )
);
wp_remote_request( $url, $args );
```

Is it possible to do http digest based authentication using `wp_remote_get` function?

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to do HTTP DIGEST authentication with `wp_remote_get()`, but it's somewhat complicated. I've written a [short wrapper function](http://blog.handbuilt.co/2016/01/08/using-http-digest-authentication-with-wordpress-wp_remote_get/) you can use.

Comment: That link no longer works. You can view it in the wayback machine here: https://web.archive.org/web/20160108195140/http://blog.handbuilt.co/2016/01/08/using-http-digest-authentication-with-wordpress-wp_remote_get/

Answer (score 0):

Isn't that obvious? *wp_remote_get* is just a single request response function. The difference, as far as wp_remote_get is concerned is that basic authentication is just *one* request response and hence just one call to wp_remote_get.

For digest based authentication, you have to make four request-response = four wp_remote_get calls.